# Low Graphics Mode Ubuntu 16.04.5 only occurs without external monitor

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, multiple-monitors

I am experiencing a very weird issue with my fresh Ubuntu 16.04.5 install. After installing, I switched to use the latest graphics driver from nvidia (396). Everything is working fine, so long as my external monitors are plugged in to my laptop.

If I try to boot without the monitors plugged in, the "low graphics mode" message appears. I honestly have looked through probably every instance of "low graphics mode" error on the internet, and I can't figure out why this is happening.

I can update this with any logs you think would help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using an hp dock with a lightning port. This is not compatible with Ubuntu 16 and my computer (hp zbook 15 g4). Just removed dock and plugged in external monitor to computer directly.